# как считать весь текст из файла в c++ в указатель на char

Tags: c++, указатели, char, fstream

```
      char *t = new char;
      ifstream fin("in.txt");
```

учитывая пробелы

Comment: В вашем варианте можно считать ровно 1 `char`, потому что именно столько вы выделили памяти...

Answer (score 3):

Как-то так:

```
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    ifstream fin("in.txt",ios_base::in|ios_base::binary);
    if (!fin.good()) return 1;

    fin.seekg(0,ios_base::end);
    size_t uSize = fin.tellg();
    fin.seekg(0);

    char* t = new char[uSize+1];
    fin.read(t,uSize);
    t[uSize] = 0;

    puts(t);

    delete[] t;
    return 0;
}
```

Второй вариант, для тестовых файлов более приемлемый:

```
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    ifstream fin("in.txt");  //теперь файл открываем как текстовый
    if (!fin.good()) return 1;

    fin.seekg(0,ios_base::end);
    size_t uSize = fin.tellg();
    fin.seekg(0);

    char* t = new char[uSize+1];
    fin.read(t,uSize);
    t[fin.gcount()] = 0;  //реальная длина строки может быть меньше размера файла

    puts(t);

    delete[] t;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Появляются символы, которых не должно быть. символы  ’ “ неправильно считываются((((

Comment: @Ildar Yumagulov значит у вас поток инициализируется как fin("in.txt"), а в моём примере - fin("in.txt",ios_base::in|ios_base::binary). А всё потому, что по умолчанию файл считается текстовым, и при чтении из него все пары "\r\n" (0xD 0xA) заменяются на одиночные "\n" (0xA), из-за чего длина строки становится меньше размера файла , отсюда и мусорные символы в конце. Флаг ios_base::binary как раз исправляет этот момент, так как для двоичных файлов никакой постобработки при чтении не производится. 
Однако, в ответ я добавил второй вариант кода, уже для текстового файла.

Comment: @Ildar Yumagulov, значит читайте про кодировку текстов.